# Finding an angle satisfying negative cosine

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find a number $\theta$ satisfying $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ such that $cos\ \theta = -\frac{1}{2}$

Now, from what I've been taught this 'seems' relatively straightforward:

Let $O$ be the origin $(0,0)$ on the plane, then with plane geometry we find the point $(-1, \sqrt3)$ whose distance from $O$ is $2$. The angle from this however does not satisfy the question; and in fact the point seems to be $(1, -\sqrt3)$ and the angle is $-\pi/3$.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Notice that $\cos $ maps $[0, \pi/2]$ onto $[0,1]$. Are you sure about the minus sign?

Comment: Are you sure about the restriction to acute angles?

Comment: @MarioG do you mean in the original question or the point $(-1, \sqrt 3)$ .

Comment: @MarioG Actually i found the error, you're right the angle is $\pi/3$ — Where from here?

Comment: @user121947: I was asking about the minus sign of $-\frac{1}{2}$. I suspect it must be $\frac{1}{2}$ (without the minus).

Answer (score 2):

To find a $\theta$ such that
$\cos(\theta)
=-\frac12
$
you have to extend
the domain of $\theta$
to
$[0, \pi]$.
$\cos(\theta)
\ge 0
$ for 
$-\pi/2 \le \theta
\le \pi/2
$.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense, the angle that satisfies $-\pi/3$ works. However where am i going off in finding it?

I got my answer by finding the that for $cos\ \theta = -\frac{1}{2}$ we have $sin\ \theta = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and a ray from the origin $O$ to $(-1, \sqrt 3)$ doesnt give me $-\pi/3$

Comment: $(-1, \sqrt{3})$ is in the second quadrant, and its angle measured from the x-axis is $2\pi/3$.